# how to map Many to Many with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have the following tables

```
Trainingplan
    TrainingplanID int(11) AI PK
    Trainer int(11)
    Client int(11)
    validFrom date
    validTo date
    type int(11)

TrainingplanExercises
    trainingplan int(11) PK
    exercise int(11) PK
    parameter int(11) PK
    value varchar(45)
```

No I have problems connecting them with Hibernate. I did the following:
package beans;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Trainingplan")
public class Training {

    private IntegerProperty id;
    private ObjectProperty<Person> client;
    private ObjectProperty<Person> trainer;
    private ObjectProperty<Date> validFrom;
    private ObjectProperty<Date> validTo;
    private ObjectProperty<TrainingplanType> type;
    private List<TrainingplanExercise> exercises;

    public Training(int id, Person client, Person trainer, Date validFrom, Date validTo, TrainingplanType type) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.client = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(client);
        this.trainer = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(trainer);
        this.validFrom = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(validFrom);
        this.validTo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(validTo);
        this.type = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(type);
        exercises = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public Training(Person client, Person trainer, Date validFrom, Date validTo, TrainingplanType type){
        this(0, client, trainer, validFrom, validTo, type);
    }

    public Training(){
        this(0, null,null,null,null, null);
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    public Person getClient() {
        return client.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Person> clientProperty() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Person client) {
        this.client.set(client);
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "trainer")
    public Person getTrainer() {
        return trainer.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Person> trainerProperty() {
        return trainer;
    }

    public void setTrainer(Person trainer) {
        this.trainer.set(trainer);
    }

    @Column
    public Date getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Date> validFromProperty() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    public void setValidFrom(Date validFrom) {
        this.validFrom.set(validFrom);
    }

    @Column
    public Date getValidTo() {
        return validTo.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Date> validTillProperty() {
        return validTo;
    }

    public void setValidTo(Date validTill) {
        this.validTo.set(validTill);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TrainingplanID")
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type")
    public TrainingplanType getType() {
        return type.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<TrainingplanType> typeProperty() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(TrainingplanType type) {
        this.type.set(type);
    }

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name="TrainingplanExercises",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="trainingplan")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="trainingplan"), @JoinColumn(name="exercise"), @JoinColumn(name="parameter")})
    public List<TrainingplanExercise> getExercises() {
        return exercises;
    }

    public void setExercises(List<TrainingplanExercise> exercises) {
        this.exercises = exercises;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Training{" +
                "id=" + getId() +
                ", client=" + getClient() +
                ", trainer=" + getTrainer() +
                ", validFrom=" + getValidFrom() +
                ", validTill=" + getValidTo() +
                ", type=" + getType() +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Training training = (Training) o;

        return id != null ? id.equals(training.id) : training.id == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

TrainingplanExercise.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingplanExercises")
@IdClass(TrainingplanExerciseId.class)
public class TrainingplanExercise {

    private ObjectProperty<Exercise> exercise;
    private ObjectProperty<Training> training;
    private ObjectProperty<String> value;
    private ObjectProperty<Parameter> parameter;

    public TrainingplanExercise(Exercise exercise, Training training, String value, Parameter parameter){
        this.exercise = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(exercise);
        this.training = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(training);
        this.value = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(value);
        this.parameter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(parameter);
    }

    public TrainingplanExercise(){
        this(null,null,null,null);
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parameter")
    public Parameter getParameter() {
        return parameter.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Parameter> parameterProperty() {
        return parameter;
    }

    public void setParameter(Parameter parameter) {
        this.parameter.set(parameter);
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exercise")
    public Exercise getExercise() {
        return exercise.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Exercise> exerciseProperty() {
        return exercise;
    }

    public void setExercise(Exercise exercise) {
        this.exercise.set(exercise);
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "trainingplan")
    public Training getTraining() {
        return training.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Training> trainingProperty() {
        return training;
    }

    public void setTraining(Training training) {
        this.training.set(training);
    }

    @Column(name = "value")
    public String getValue(){
        return value.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<String> valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TrainingplanExercise{" + "exercise=" + exercise + ", training=" + training + ", value=" + value + '}';
    }

}

 class TrainingplanExerciseId implements Serializable{
     protected ObjectProperty<Exercise> exercise;
     protected ObjectProperty<Training> training;
     protected ObjectProperty<Parameter> parameter;

     public TrainingplanExerciseId() {
         if(exercise == null)
             exercise = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);

         if(training == null)
             training = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);

         if(parameter == null)
             parameter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
     }

     public TrainingplanExerciseId(ObjectProperty<Exercise> exercise, ObjectProperty<Training> training, ObjectProperty<Parameter> parameter) {
         this.exercise = exercise;
         this.training = training;
         this.parameter = parameter;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (this == o) return true;
         if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

         TrainingplanExerciseId that = (TrainingplanExerciseId) o;

         if (exercise != null ? !exercise.equals(that.exercise) : that.exercise != null) return false;
         if (training != null ? !training.equals(that.training) : that.training != null) return false;
         return parameter != null ? parameter.equals(that.parameter) : that.parameter == null;

     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         int result = exercise != null ? exercise.hashCode() : 0;
         result = 31 * result + (training != null ? training.hashCode() : 0);
         result = 31 * result + (parameter != null ? parameter.hashCode() : 0);
         return result;
     }

     public Exercise getExercise() {
         return exercise.get();
     }

     public ObjectProperty<Exercise> exerciseProperty() {
         return exercise;
     }

     public void setExercise(Exercise exercise) {
         this.exercise.set(exercise);
     }

     public Training getTraining() {
         return training.get();
     }

     public ObjectProperty<Training> trainingProperty() {
         return training;
     }

     public void setTraining(Training training) {
         this.training.set(training);
     }

     public Parameter getParameter() {
         return parameter.get();
     }

     public ObjectProperty<Parameter> parameterProperty() {
         return parameter;
     }

     public void setParameter(Parameter parameter) {
         this.parameter.set(parameter);
     }
 }
```

Now when I want to save a new Training, I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'TrainingplanID' in 'field list'
```

Because of this SQL:

```
Hibernate: insert into TrainingplanExercises (TrainingplanID, trainingplan, exercise, parameter) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How do I fix this?
If I change the joinColumn to "trainingplan" I get the error that there are two same columns. If I remove "trainingplan" from the reversed columns, I get an error that one is missing because the foreign constraint requires 3 columns

EDIT:
Try something from the comments. I did try OneToMany/ManyToOne:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "trainingplan", nullable = false)
public Training getTraining() {
    return training.get();
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "training")
public List<TrainingplanExercise> getExercises() {
    return exercises;
}
```

If I try saving a training to the DB now, it works. 
Let's say I want to get a Trainingplan from the database, and add new TrainingplanExercises. I would use this code:

```
Exercise ex = (Exercise) db.getAll(Exercise.class).get(1);


Training t = (Training) db.getAll(Training.class).get(0);


TrainingplanExercise te = new TrainingplanExercise(ex, t, "asdf", ex.getParameters().get(0));
TrainingplanExercise te1 = new TrainingplanExercise(ex, t, "asdf", ex.getParameters().get(1));
TrainingplanExercise te2 = new TrainingplanExercise(ex, t, "asdf", ex.getParameters().get(2));
TrainingplanExercise te3 = new TrainingplanExercise(ex, t, "asdf", ex.getParameters().get(3));



t.getExercises().clear();
t.getExercises().add(te);
t.getExercises().add(te1);
t.getExercises().add(te2);
t.getExercises().add(te3);

db.updateObj(t);
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at db.Database.updateObj(Database.java:100)
    at db.Database.main(Database.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Would you mind to post the @ManyToMany declaration code and the exact respective error messages when you declare 'trainingPlan' as a joinColumn and remove it from inverseJoinColumn, as you described in your last paragraph ? My guess is the problem lies in there

Comment: Why it is many to many? from your data model, one Training Plan Exercise can refer to only 1 Training Plan.  It should be OneToMany / ManyToOne isn't it?

Comment: I did try to use OneToMany/ManyToOne now because I also think this is the right way to go. Still have problems, see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, look. What you have is a design problem, not really a general problem. First, as I understand it, you want to make a set of unique `TrainingplanExercise's`. For that, you have this `Entity`:

```
@Entity
public class TrainingplanExercise implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId private TrainingplanExerciseId trainingplanExerciseId;

    public TrainingplanExercise() {}        
    public TrainingplanExercise(TrainingplanExerciseId trainingplanExerciseId) {
        this.trainingplanExerciseId = trainingplanExerciseId;
    }
    ... other fields ...   
}
```

The difference between the above `Entity` and your original `Entity` is that I have made the `ID` an `EmbeddableId`. In order to insure that only unique exercises are put into the `TrainingplanExercise's`, you have a `compositeKey` that was defined as a separate class:

```
@Embeddable
public class TrainingplanExerciseId implements Serializable {
    private String exercise;
    private String parameter;

    public TrainingplanExerciseId() {}
    public TrainingplanExerciseId(String exercise, String parameter) {
        this.exercise = exercise;
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    ... getters, setters, hashCode, and equals
}
```

Here, I have made the class `Embeddable` so that it can be used as an `ID`. The way you were trying to declare a `compositeKey` didn't make any sense; you were trying to declare each individual field in the `TrainingplanExercise` `Entity` as an `ID`, but you can only have one `ID`.

What is different in this `model` is that the `TrainingplanExerciseId` `compositeKey` does not include a reference back to a `TrainingPlan`. If you are trying to get a list of `TrainingPlan's` that use any specific `TrainingplanExercise`, then you would need a [Bidirectional instead of a Unidirectional relationship](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytomany-unidirectional-bidirectional/), but that's a different issue. Otherwise, I don't know why you want to refer back to a `TrainingPlan` from a `TrainingplanExercise`. Further, you were putting a reference to the `TrainingPlan` into the `TrainingplanExerciseId` `compositeKey`, which would require the `TrainingPlan` to be serialized, which really wouldn't work as a unique Id.

Now you can put individual exercises into the table:

```
public TrainingplanExercise createExercise(String exercise, String parameter) {
    TrainingplanExercise trainingplanExercise = new TrainingplanExercise(new TrainingplanExerciseId(exercise, parameter));
    em.persist( trainingplanExercise );
    return trainingplanExercise;
}
```

After that, you want to have any number of `TrainingPlan's` that use the possible `TrainingplanExercise's`, which you do with this `Entity`:

```
@Entity
public class TrainingPlan implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TrainingplanExercise> trainingplanExercises = new ArrayList<TrainingplanExercise>();

    ... getters, setters, 
}
```

You have a `ManyToMany` relationship because a `TrainingPlan` refers to many `TrainingplanExercise's` and a `TrainingplanExercise` is used by many `TrainingPlan's`. You don't need any special annotation besides `ManyToMany`, the `JPA` provider will create a `link table`, putting the key from each `Entity` into a row, like this:

```
create table TrainingPlan_TrainingplanExercise (
    TrainingPlan_id bigint not null,
    trainingplanExercises_exercise varchar(255) not null,
    trainingplanExercises_parameter varchar(255) not null
);
```

If you declare it as a `OneToMany` relationship, then the `JPA` provider will put an additional `constraint` on the `link table` insuring that a `TrainingplanExercise` cannot be linked to more than one `TrainingPlan`, so you don't want that. Just for example's sake, this is what the constraint would look like.

```
alter table TrainingPlan_TrainingplanExercise 
    add constraint UK_t0ku26ydvjkrme5ycrnlechgi  unique (trainingplanExercises_exercise, trainingplanExercises_parameter);
```

Creating and updating `TrainingPlans` is straight forward:

```
public TrainingPlan createTrainingPlan() {
    TrainingPlan trainingPlan = new TrainingPlan();
    em.persist(trainingPlan);
    return trainingPlan;
}
public TrainingPlan updateTrainingPlan(TrainingPlan trainingPlan) {
    return em.merge(trainingPlan);
}
```

Now, you can create `TrainingplanExercises` and `TrainingPlans`, and add the exercises to the training plans and update them.

```
TrainingplanExercise squats20 = trainingService.createExercise("Squats", "20");
TrainingplanExercise lifts10 = trainingService.createExercise("Lifts", "10");
TrainingplanExercise crunches50 = trainingService.createExercise("Crunches", "50");

TrainingPlan trainingPlan = trainingService.createTrainingPlan();
trainingPlan.getTrainingplanExercises().add( squats20 );
trainingPlan.getTrainingplanExercises().add( lifts10 );
trainingService.updateTrainingPlan(trainingPlan);

trainingPlan = trainingService.createTrainingPlan();
trainingPlan.getTrainingplanExercises().add( lifts10 );
trainingPlan.getTrainingplanExercises().add( crunches50 );
trainingService.updateTrainingPlan(trainingPlan);
```

Also note that your application has the challenge of insuring that only unique `TrainingplanExercises` are created by users. If a `TrainingplanExercise` with a duplicate `exercise` and `parameter` is attempted to be created you will get a `Unique index or primary key violation` exception and the transaction will be rolled back.

EDIT: For reading the `TrainingPlans`, something like this can be used:

```
public List<TrainingPlan> listTrainingPlans() {
    CriteriaQuery<TrainingPlan> criteria = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(TrainingPlan.class);
    criteria.select(criteria.from(TrainingPlan.class));
    List<TrainingPlan> trainingPlans = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    return trainingPlans;
}
```

Note that since the `List<TrainingplanExercise> trainingplanExercises` is set to `FetchType.EAGER` this particular query will pull in the entire database. `FetchType.EAGER` probably isn't a problem for reading a single `TrainingPlan`, but if you only wanted a list of the `TrainingPlan's` without getting all of the details, then you would need to work out how `FetchType.LAZY` should be implemented.

Comment: Many thanks! It seems to work that I can insert something. Although if I want to read from database, I get an Error `ERROR: Table 'bla.TrainingplanExercise' doesn't exist`. I did everything as described above

Comment: Added an edit on reading. If the table doesn't exist, then I don't know how you can insert into it, so there must be more to your error than I can easily see. Note that I didn't use name= in my table annotation, so you need to be sure you are using the correct table name, perhaps `TrainingplanExercises`. Please accept answer if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I've created the table `TrainingPlan_TrainingplanExercise`this is very the value is saved. When I want to read it, hibernate wants to select from `TrainingplanExercise`. I've added the name= annotation and set it to `@Table(name = "TrainingplanExercise")`. However, now it wants to read from `Trainingplan_TrainingplanExercise` that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You should either have persistence.xml configured to generate the schema or create a class to generate the schema and a .ddl file. Describing that here is getting too far away from this original question, but there are many SO answers and tutorials on those things.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using many-to-one mapping instead because it's what you have with a foreign key anyway. You could then try something like:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, targetEntity=Trainingplan.class )
@JoinColumn(name = "trainingplan")
public Training getTraining() {}
```