# Jpa/Hibernate Composite Key with many to one and @IdClass detached entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities **Train** and **Station**. They have @OneToMany relation on **Timetable** entity. In Timetable entity I have composite key on Train and Station as @ManyToOne.

**All classes have setters and getters**

**Train**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "train")
public class Train {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "train",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("curentnumber ASC")
    private List<Coach> coaches;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "train",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("arrivalTime ASC")
    private List<Timetable> timetable ;
    ...
}
```

**Station**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "station")
public class Station {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 16, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "station", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Timetable> timetable;

    ...
}
```

**Timetable**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TimetableId.class)
@Table(name = "timetable")
public class Timetable implements Serializable, Comparable<Timetable>{

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "train_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Train train;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "station_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Station station;

    @Column(name = "arrivalTime")
    private Timestamp arrivalTime;

    @Column(name = "departureTime")
    private Timestamp departureTime;

    ...
}
```

**TimetableId**

```
public class TimetableId implements Serializable{

    Long train;
    Long station;

    public TimetableId() {
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TimetableId that = (TimetableId) o;

        if (train != null ? !train.equals(that.train) : that.train != null) return false;
        return station != null ? station.equals(that.station) : that.station == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = train.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + station.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have service class too.

```
//Result timetable
Timetable addedTimetable = new Timetable();

addedTimetable.setTrain(new Train());
addedTimetable.getTrain().setId(Long.valueOf(trainid));
addedTimetable.setStation(new Station());
addedTimetable.getStation().setId(Long.valueOf(stationid));
try{
    timetableRepository.create(addedTimetable);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**And some from GenericDAO**

```
@Override
public void create(T entity) {
    EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        try {
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.persist(entity);
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally {
            if (manager.getTransaction().isActive())
                manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I have @IdClass annotation and try to create new Timetable referenced on new Station() and new Train with existing id, then i get error for "detached entity passed to persist:entity.Station" in my dao level. But if i remove @IdClass annotation, then everything is good and Timetable creates correctly. I think that i make something wrong in TimetableId and annotations...

Please help me, i stack here.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [how to map Many to Many with composite key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111950/how-to-map-many-to-many-with-composite-key/35249057#35249057).

Comment: "The problem is when I have @IdClass annotation and try to create new Timetable referenced on new Station() and new Train with existing id": If they are existing entities then you need to load these existing entities and set these as references. Simply setting the ID is not going to work.

Comment: @AlanHay I tried to load Station and Train using findBy but exception is stil here. Or you suggest to do it when transaction begin?